# How to add Active X component to C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, activex

I'm creating in a Windows forms application using VS2008. I need to add ActiveX controls to it. But unable to do so.

this example is what i try to achieve [LINK](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/3693-net-interoperability-glance-3---unmanaged.aspx) sub topic *"Interop with ActiveX Controls"*

The following are the steps provided to achieve it, but i cant find the below mentioned options in my Visual studio.

> (1) When you have a form displayed, right-click the Toolbox and select "Choose Items".
>
> (2) Click the "COM Components" tab.
>
> (3) Locate your ActiveX control and tick the box for it anc click
>   "OK".
>
> (4) Now it should appear on the toolbox; drag and drop it onto your
>   form and set its properties.

Comment: did you try to register your active X dll by using regsrv32 cmd?

Comment: i want to use existing active x component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Open the windows form file that you want to add an Activex control.
- Right click on **any tool** on the tool box.
- That menu contains **"Choose Items"**.
- Click on it and you can see the COM Components tab on the pop up window.
- Select any COM component that you want to add.
- Then it appears on the tool box.
- Drag and drop it on to the form.

Comment: Hi, How can I use in reverse. Please refer my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045424/how-to-convert-a-c-sharp-dll-to-activex-object-to-use-in-vb6)