# Adding reference dll in VS 2010 got error when migrating the project using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I add reference from the `project`->`add reference` and when running the program it's ok, but when I try to migrate my project folder to another computer. I will get this error

```
    `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with 
     CLSID {20B43BA5-9CE9-42E1-9A56-B049C8828B1C} 
     failed due to the following error: 
       80040154 Class not registered 
     (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).`
```

and the reference folder I added the  dll from, has a yellow punctuation icon, how can I possibly fix this?

I copy the dll to the pc that where i migrated my project and then when I add the dll this give me error tsssk

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you checked if the library exists on the target machine? Are the .NET versions equal?

Comment: try adding reference of dll again.

Comment: Is the image working? Try uploading it using the StackOverflow image upload button at the top of the text editor.

Comment: @rhughes cant upload sir

Comment: @cheol.lui Is this DLL an actual .NET DLL?

Comment: Is it an activex component? then try steps from here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678814/how-to-add-active-x-component-to-c-sharp-project and http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/3693-net-interoperability-glance-3---unmanaged.aspx

Comment: I can't post my answer I actually solved it by in cmd REGSVR32 dllpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the reference location is not available on the new machine. Verify that the reference file and the location are on the new machine.

If they are, remove and re-add the reference.

Comment: I've done that already . the dll has still yellow punctuation mark :(

Comment: If you right click on the reference and then click Properties, you will see the location of the reference. If you copy and paste that reference location into a Windows Explorer window, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

When you change to location of project or move your visual studio project from one location to another location. then it checks the Private assembly references you have added in your project on the location where you were using from last time. so to solve this just add these references again or put the ref library's into the location where visual studio is seeking for.

better to create a folder under you project and add all your local assemblies into that and add ref from here.

Comment: YEs i ve done that already i updated my question see my error output