# Can I use COleControlModule in a vb.net windows forms app?

Tags: c++, winforms, activex

I am upgrading a windows forms app. The app uses an active x control (ocx) file. We have gotten the ocx to compile and can register it. The main class in the C++ active x control project is a COleControlModule. When I go to add the control to the windows forms app like this

```
Me.Controls.Add(Me.ActiveXClass)
```

I get

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 
'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.
```

I know the active x class is a com object and I know that this COleControlModule class must not be compatible with a windows forms control. Is there anything I can do to make this work?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Aximp.exe to generate a Windows Forms control wrapper around the ActiveX control. In a Visual Studio WinForms application, you can have this done automatically by adding a reference to the ActiveX control in the project's references in Solution Manager.

Comment: It needs an AxHost to find a happy home.  Easiest way to generate one is to add it to the toolbox first.  Right-click > Choose Items > Browse tab.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill If you'd written this + a few steps what to do in your answer, it would be probably better received.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Answer is deleted.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill Yeah, know (I can see your deleted answer). You may still edit to improve it, and undelete it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am getting closer. I did Hans' method and now I am having some other errors but I think they are related to permissions.

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678814/how-to-add-active-x-component-to-c-sharp-project

It details the steps to add an ActiveX control to a Winforms form.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  Answer is reworked as you suggested and undeleted.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't working because a Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW) is not a Windows Forms control. Only Windows Forms controls will work; to use an ActiveX control with the form, you must generate a Windows Forms wrapper for the ActiveX control. This is done with [Aximp.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/aximp-exe-windows-forms-activex-control-importer), typically via adding the control to the Toolbox, as Hans suggested and then dragging an instance of the control to the form.

The steps are:

1. Select 'Choose Items, either from the Tools menu or by right-clicking the Tools tab
2. Select the COM Components tab
3. Select the ActiveX control either directly from the list or through the Browse button
4. From the Tools dialog, select the newly-added component with the mouse and drag it to the form.

A reference to the ActiveX control will be added to the project, as in this sample with the Adobe PDF reader:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="AcroPDFLib">
      <Guid>{05BFD3F1-6319-4F30-B752-C7A22889BCC4}</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Isolated>False</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
    <COMReference Include="AxAcroPDFLib">
      <Guid>{05BFD3F1-6319-4F30-B752-C7A22889BCC4}</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <WrapperTool>aximp</WrapperTool>
      <Isolated>False</Isolated>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Note there are two entries, one to generate a Runtime Callable Wrapper (via tlbimp), and another to generate the AxImp wrapper (via aximp). These will be viewable in Solution View, under the project's references.

Comment: R.J. do I have to do anything if I change the active x control? If I add a method, do I have to do anything with Aximp to see and use the method in the windows form?

Comment: Do you mean modifying the ActiveX control? Rebuilding should force a regeneration of all the wrappers.